# Unable to run the SQL Queries reading from SQLite connecting through Java to DB

Tags: java, sql, database, sqlite

I have my queries in `SQLite DB`. I want to run these queries on a different `DB` reading through Java. I am able to run the same queries on SQL developer manually copying from `SQLite`.

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character
```

will come when executed through java program. There is no wrong in program as well as query. Please tell me where I am leaving the track.(It has no semicolons in the end. I have checked it).

Comment: Do you have a trace of the query being executed from Java?  Its probably do to a misquoted string.

Comment: It was "�" character which was creeping in. finally was able to figure it out. I am now removing via string.replace method. Thanks